# Missing matchType at HERE geocoding responses

Tags: here-api

HERE Geocoding docs say that [there's a "MatchType" result ("quality of the location match, either pointAddress or interpolated")](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/topics/reading-geocoding-response.html). Nevertheless, I'm not receiving it. Here's a curl example request:

```
$ curl -G https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json --data-urlencode "app_id=XXX" --data-urlencode "app_code=YYYY" --data-urlencode "searchtext=Plaza España, Valladolid, Spain" | json_pp
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   916  100   916    0     0   4182      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4182
{
   "Response" : {
      "MetaInfo" : {
         "Timestamp" : "2018-07-11T12:21:43.726+0000"
      },
      "View" : [
         {
            "_type" : "SearchResultsViewType",
            "Result" : [
               {
                  "MatchQuality" : {
                     "Country" : 1,
                     "City" : 1,
                     "District" : 1
                  },
                  "Location" : {
                     "DisplayPosition" : {
                        "Latitude" : 41.65039,
                        "Longitude" : -4.72559
                     },
                     "LocationType" : "point",
                     "MapView" : { 
                        "BottomRight" : { 
                           "Longitude" : -4.71874,
                           "Latitude" : 41.64807
                        },  
                        "TopLeft" : { 
                           "Longitude" : -4.72961,
                           "Latitude" : 41.65196
                        }   
                     },  
                     "LocationId" : "NT_zM4WS5CjEFeGmNW-rZko9A",
                     "Address" : { 
                        "District" : "Plaza España",
                        "County" : "Valladolid",
                        "Country" : "ESP",
                        "City" : "Valladolid",
                        "State" : "Castilla y León",
                        "PostalCode" : "47002",
                        "Label" : "Plaza España, Valladolid, Castilla y León, España",
                        "AdditionalData" : [ 
                           {   
                              "value" : "España",
                              "key" : "CountryName"
                           },
                           {   
                              "key" : "StateName",
                              "value" : "Castilla y León"
                           },
                           {
                              "value" : "Valladolid",
                              "key" : "CountyName"
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     "NavigationPosition" : [
                        {
                           "Longitude" : -4.72559,
                           "Latitude" : 41.65039
                        }
                     ]
                  },
                  "Relevance" : 1,
                  "MatchLevel" : "district"
               }
            ],
            "ViewId" : 0
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, in other search, it appeared: `"MatchType" : "interpolated"`. Does it appear only if the result is interpolated?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation isn't very clear on this one.

The **MatchType** indicates the precision of a house number match.  If the place has an address you will get a *pointAddress* or *interpolated*, but if there is no house number at all MatchType is excluded from the response.  The *interpolated* response happens if the data comes from an address range so the bounding box is calculated for that location, for example units 1-4 are identified as townhouses in a building but you searched for unit 3.

In this example, since it appears like you are searching for a landmark the precision of the number address matchType doesn't come through in the response.